# Is it possible to pull Flickr photos based on search term?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, api, flickr

Is it possible to pull photos from the Flickr API based on a search term? Not necessarily something from my profile, but from any public photo that matches the search term.

Or is the Flickr API only for pulling your own, or another authenticated users, photos?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html

> Return a list of photos matching some
>   criteria. Only photos visible to the
>   calling user will be returned. To
>   return private or semi-private photos,
>   the caller must be authenticated with
>   'read' permissions, and have
>   permission to view the photos.
>   Unauthenticated calls will only return
>   public photos.

Answer (score 2):

> **Many** methods require the user to be logged in.

— http://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.userauth.html

i.e. not all

> Unauthenticated calls will only return public photos.

— http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html

Comment: Very nice, much appreciated for the answer. I'm at my office PC and the firewall's blocking certain portions of Flickr... ;(